# Set the image property of an UIImageView - Does not Work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

Below is the relevant code

.h

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *productImageView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *productImageView;
```

.m

```
@synthesize productImageView
```

in the initWithNibName custom initialization:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myurl.net/test.jpg"]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
productImageView.image = image;
```

Comment: in your initWithNibName are you calling [super initWithNibName]; ?

Comment: It is inside the following if :

if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myurl.net/test.jpg"]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
productImageView.image = image;

}

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't forget the semicolon after the `@synthesize` directive.
2. Have you connected the `IBOutlet` to your controller in Interface Builder?
3. You have a memory leak: an `UIImageView` retains its image, so you need to `release` the one you allocate in your method.